# How do I check for a salted password in Spring Security?

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, salt

I am using Spring 3 and grabbing users from a MySQL database.

Right now, in testing, I have a user with a MD5 password.  And I can authenticate just fine using that.

However, we want to be a little more secure in how we hash the passwords.  We want to:

```
MD5(username + salt + password)
```

The salt is a random string stored in the user record.  But I can't seem to figure out where/how to do this.  This is what I have so far:

**UserDao**

```
public class UserDao {

    public static Users findUserByUsername(String paUsername) {
        String hql = "from Users where username = :username";

        List<Users> list = null;
        Users user = null;

        try {
            IO io = new IO("web");   // custom Hibernate framework
            IOQuery query = new IOQuery();
            query.setStatement(hql);
            query.setParameter(new IOParameter("username", paUsername));

            list = io.runQuery(query);

            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }

            return list.get(0);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl**

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String paUsername) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users user = userDao.findUserByUsername(paUsername);

        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }

        return new User(
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                user.getEnabled(),
                true,
                true,
                true,
                getAuthorities(Enums.UserRoles.IT));
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Enums.UserRoles paRole) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(paRole));
        return authList;
    }

    private List<String> getRoles(Enums.UserRoles paRole) {
        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();

        if (paRole.equals(Enums.UserRoles.USER)) {
            roles.add(Enums.UserRoles.USER.name());
        } else if (paRole.equals(Enums.UserRoles.IT)) {
            roles.add(Enums.UserRoles.USER.name());
            roles.add(Enums.UserRoles.IT.name());
        }

        return roles;
    }

    private static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> paRoles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String role : paRoles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

**UserDetailsService**

```
public class UserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl().loadUserByUsername(username);        
    }
}
```

**security-app-context**

```
<beans:bean id="loginSuccessHandler" class="com.myapp.security.LoginSuccessHandler" />
<beans:bean id="loginFailureHandler" class="com.myapp.security.LoginFailureHandler" />
<beans:bean id="detailsService" class="com.myapp.security.UserDetailService" />
```

Any ideas on what I need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fragment of the security config my app uses to set password encoding:

```
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
</sec:authentication-manager>


<bean id="authenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsServiceImpl"/>
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="cryptoPasswordEncoder" />
</bean>


<bean id="cryptoPasswordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />
```

We don't need to set a Salt source in the [DaoAuthenticationProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html) because the [BCryptPasswordEncoder](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html) uses its own.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
public class PasswordEncoder extends org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder{             

    public PasswordEncoder() {
        super("MD5");
    }

    @Override
    public String encodePassword(String originalPassword, Object salt) {
            // here supply salt = username + saltString
        String encryptedPassword =  super.encodePassword(originalPassword, salt);           
        return encryptedPassword;
    }

}
```

Comment: How do I get Spring to reference this?

Comment: @cbmeeks use `String encryptedPassword = new PasswordEncoder().encodePassword(pass, salt);`. Check API for MessageDigestPasswordEncoder here http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.html